# enable SSL on mongodb on windows

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-mongodb

I search in the internet but unfortunately there is not a good document that help to emable SSL on mongodb on Windows.
I have Spring Restful server that CRUD with mongodb. is there any example guide to help me to do that ?

thanks in advance

Comment: any help is appreciated